# Why does the popup in elementor closes after form submit?

Tags: wordpress, popup, elementor

I have a contact form in my popup using elementor pro, as soon as I click the submit button it closes the popup without me having clicked the close button. How can I prevent it from closing, as I need to see the confirmation message?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmH6j.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can set it on this https://docs.elementor.com/article/343-actions-after-submit, but since your form is popup already, I doubt you can create another popup to make some confirmation dialog